# How to get a mean of all rows containing a specific string in any of the columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I've got a pandas data frame with answers to a hypothetical survey. There are two questions: "which of the colors on the American flag is your favorite (you may pick more than one)?" and "what is your monthly salary?"
There are several possible answers to the first question:

```
1. red, white, blue
2. red, white
3. red, blue
4. red
5. white, blue
6. white
7. blue
```

I want to get the average salary values of all people who in their answer to the first question included red, white, and blue respectively.
I want to get something like this:

```
FlagColor Salary 
red       4345
white     3444
blue      2356
```

I got to a point where I have mean values for all the options, I used something like this:

`flagcolors_vs_salary_mean = flagcolors_vs_salary.dropna().groupby('FlagColor' , as_index=False)['Salary'].mean()`

How do I combine the means from all the options that include each color? Do I need to split the column with the answers to the first question? Remember that the number of people who voted for each option varies between the options.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You can use pandas [series.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to select/filter your dataframe to only rows that contain certain strings

Comment: If you want to use `groupby()` you need to put each selected color in its own row, not a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 2):

Try exploding the flag color first into its own rows, then use `groupby`:

```
(df.assign(**{'FlagColor': df['FlagColor'].str.split(', ')})
   .explode('FlagColor')
   .groupby('FlagColor', as_index=False)['Salary']
   .mean())
```